# HTML add file inside page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to build a website. I have a menu and I want it to be included in all my other files. I have tried PHP and JS and failed. What is wrong with the code and what is happening?

**Index.html** (Yes I tried Index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- ADD MENU HERE -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h3>Text</h3>
                    <li>© 2014 Text.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Menu.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">stuff
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Help<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="hi.html">hi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="text.html">text</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">HIIIII<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="food.html">Food</a></li>
                                <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Tools<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Hellp</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Link">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="uh.html">uh</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
```

So what should I do?

**Edit**: I changed them the extension .php and added the line `<?php include 'Menu.php'; ?>` into  and there still is no menu.

Comment: what happened when you did php include? Or did nothing happen. Could you describe?

Comment: Post a copy of the .htaccess file for us. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rename index.html to index.php

And in index.php, add a line:

`<?php
Include 'menu.hml';
?>`

Comment: I did that. Nothing happened.

Comment: It should work. Where did you include the menu.html?

Comment: I put  <?php include 'menu.hml'; ?> in <body>

Comment: I use this syntax--may end up being the same thing: <?php include('whatever.html'); ?>

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe it was a possible syntax error. Good luck! You may try creating a test and include another 'test' php file. The php file could just echo 'test' that way you can see if that works.

Comment: @www139 I found something wierd. I try to echo in the tags <html> and the screen comes out blank. What does this mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I would suggest taking a close look at your code. Looks like a possible syntax error. Turn on php error reporting (if you have it turned off). Also look at the page through your browser inspector and describe what you see. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: Would you post the contents of your .htaccess file on SO? That may be your problem. It appears as though your server isn't running. Php isn't running.

Comment: Is your .htaccess file setup to run php code in a .html file extension?

Comment: What is the file extension of the page with the php include statement

Answer (score 1):

Save Menu.html as Menu.php. Then use

```
<?php include 'Menu.php'; ?>
```

to include it in your web files.

Comment: Don't forget he needs to change the extension of index.html to index.php

Comment: You can include html files. Thus it needs to be index.php, but menu.html can remain as an html file.

Comment: It depends on how the server is configured, that;s why I removed that bit. But yes, if you are not utilizing PHP as the handler for HTML documents, you would have to rename the file to a .php file.

Comment: I did that. Nothing happened.

Comment: did you try making both the menu file and the web file both .php files?

Comment: @BAsh Yes I did. I put the line in <body>

Comment: is it possible the files are not in the same directory? you would have to specify the correct path(relative is usually better) to the Menu.php file

Comment: i would suggest you enable php error reporting, and see why it's failing